# Create document swagger for azure function api (typescript)

Tags: typescript, azure, swagger, azure-functions

I need your help please.

I created a Rest api with **azure function**, which allows to return a list of users from a cosmoDB database hosted in the cloud.

I wanted to create the **swagger** documentation for this api, knowing that I use azure function v2 with the language **typescript** for my api.

This is my code type script (index.ts)

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { CosmosClient } from "@azure/cosmos";  // @azure/cosmos c'est notre kit Azure Cosmos DB SQL JavaScript SDK 
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function(
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  try {


    const client = new CosmosClient(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING); 
    const database = client.database(process.env.COSMOS_DB_NAME);
    const container = database.container(process.env.COSMOS_DB_COLLECTION1_NAME);

    
    let iterator = container.items.readAll();
    let { resources } = await iterator.fetchAll();
    
    context.res = {
      body: resources
    };

  } catch (err) {
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      body: err.message
    };
  }
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

[Projet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T92Zp.png)

And this is my file swagger.yml

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: APIAzureFunction
  version: '2.0'
host: localhost:7071
basePath: /api
schemes:
  - https
  - http
paths:
  '/utilisateurs':
    get:
      tags:
        - Utilisateurs
      summary: Retourner toutes les utilisateurs.
      consumes:
        - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: la liste des utilisateurs
          schema:
            type: object
            required:
              - userName
            properties:
              id:
                type: string
              nom:
                type: string
              prénom:
                type: string
              mdp:
                type: number
              Active:
                type: boolean
```

preview in swagger [swagger preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbX3J.png)

I would like to display the list of users in swagger, to do that i wrote the documentation yml (swagger.yml),
When i execute a request get users in swagger editor i get this error : TypeError: Failed to fetch.

this is a picture for error :[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please tell me where you call the api? Is that you test the api in the swagger editor?

Comment: Besides, could you please use fiddler to catch your request to get detailed error message?

Comment: hi @JimXu , thanks for your answer, in fact I call my api from swagger preview of VSCode, I tested it on postman and a web browser it works well.

Comment: I have like error "TypeError: Failed to fetch " in Swagger Preview

Comment: @JimXu, I have no error on fiddler, my request runs successfully, but on vscode swagger preview or swagger editor I have this error : Failed to fetch

Comment: Ok. I see. I will do a test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the information you provide, I can reproduce the issue. It is a cors issue. The VS code swagger preview or swagger editor is a single page application. when we can API from a different domain in them, we will face cors issue. So we need to configure CORS for our azure function. Regarding how to  configure it, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#cors)

For example

my file swagger.yml

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: APIAzureFunction
  version: '2.0'
host: localhost:7071
basePath: /api
schemes:
  - http
paths:
  '/http':
    get:
      tags:
        - Http
      summary: query cosmos db.
      consumes:
        - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: response
```

my function code

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"
import { CosmosClient } from "@azure/cosmos";
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    try {


        const client = new CosmosClient(''); 
        const database = client.database('');
        const container = database.container('');
    
        
        let iterator = container.items.readAll();
        let { resources } = await iterator.fetchAll();
        
        context.res = {
          body: resources,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        };
    
      } catch (err) {
        context.res = {
          status: 500,
          body: err.message
        };
      }
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

- I do not configure CORS for my function

[image]

- I configure CORS for function(I test on local)

Please add the following settings in `local.settings.json` to implement it

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
    
  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @Jim Xu, sorry I saw your answer late, that’s exactly what I did and it worked perfectly, and if I understood correctly, the swagger editor runs on a different port than the local machine ?